# How would I remove SCREEN ORIENTATION on the android native app?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, screen-orientation

Please explain how can I remove screen orientation from PhoneGap android application in eclipse.

My app was unexpectedly closed when I am trying to rotate my phone. I need to remove that.
I don't need the rotation system at all.

Please pick up a solution with explain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know about PhoneGap, but I add "android:screenOrientation="portrait"" as an attribute to the <activity> tag inside the manifest.xml

Comment: yes... I also did that but it returning errors.

Comment: I keep seeing this in apps, and its really awkward that its not following the standard behavior of following orientation, it kind of like a lazy implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` or `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in `activity Tag` of Manifest file depending on  your requirement and your application will behave as you have set the orienation.

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest file just add below code in your `<activity>` tag

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity" android:label="Application Name" android:screenOrientation="YourOrientation">
```

If you're using more than one activity means, and that activity also wants to perform with desired orientation means, just do like above code. Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your question but I think you essentially want to prevent your application from switching orientations whenever the user rotates the phone. You can do that by adding the screenOrientation attribute to your manifest file. It would look something like this:

This would keep your application locked in a portrait orientation even if the user rotates the phone.

Comment: yes you got it.... I need portrait orientation forever. Please explain the system of modifying of AndroidManiFest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for, but Lalit have already answerd it, but here is in code way:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".MyActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Just tell your activity in the manifest.xml file that you always want it in portrait, if that is what you want!

GL